# Read all ad campaign from Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using [Facebook Marketing API](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/act_109044369289538/adcampaign_groups?access_token=) to get ad campaingn from Facebook. I'm getting the data, but the problem is, they are sending the data with pagination. I have the url for the next set of data, so I need to call the Facebook API multiple times. I can set the data limit in the request to a huge number so that I can get all the data at a time.

Is there any other option to get all the data?

I tried with until & since parameter and sending the timestamp of current time & 0, but it didn't worked.

So is there any other way out?

Answer (score 1):

Paging through the data is the way to go. There is no alternative.

There are indeed different ways to use paging, one of which would be to use the `next`/`previous` links provided in a response. Another way is to use so-called Cursor-Based Pagination, where you construct your own next/previous links using a provided cursor tokens. This is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging).

Please not that you *can* indeed change the requested `limit` to some huge number, but Facebook's API may silently reduce that number to whatever it thinks is sensible, or it may return an error saying that you requested too much data. Summarized, this means you will need to use paging.